# How to build relationship between tables in quill?

Tags: database, scala, relationship, slick, quill

When we working on **slick**, we can define the database design with all *primary* and *foreign* keys as following.

```
val id = column[Int]("department_id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
```

```
def employee = foreignKey("employee_id_fk", id, employeeTableQuery)(_.id)
```

But now I'm working on a **quill** project with a **mysql** database and Normally we use only the simple case class as following.

```
case class Student(id: Int, name: String, address: Option[String])
```

All I want to know, how to define the database design in **quill**